# Python Fix Dependancy Cycle

Tags: python

I'm working on a game using python.

The AI in the game uses variables that the player has, and vice versa.

For an example:

```
class Player():
    def __init__(self, canvas...):
        self.id = canvas.create_rectangle(...)
        ...
    def touching_AI(self):
        aipos = canvas.coords(AI object)
        pos = canvas.coords(self.id)
        ...

    #the function above checks if the player is touching the AI if it 
    #is, then call other functions

this = player(canvas...)

class AI():
   def __init__(self, canvas...):
       self.id = canvas.create_rectangle(...)
   def chase_player(self):
       playerpos = canvas.coords(this.id)
       pos = canvas.coords(self.id)
       ...
       # a lot of code that isn't important
```

Obviously, Python says that the AI object in the player class isn't defined. Both classes depend on the other to work. However, one isn't defined yet, so if I put one before the other, it returns an error. While there is probably a workaround for these two functions only, there are more functions that I didn't mention.

In summary, is there a way (pythonic or non-pythonic) to use and/or define an object before it is created (i.e even making more files)?

Comment: there's lots of syntax errors in your code example ...  and its not clear at all what `AI.object` is supposed to be... is it a classmethod? is it a class attribute? is it actually an instance attribute?

Comment: ok to clarify my code isn't supposed to be good it's just slight bits of it so it makes a bit of sense. `AI.object` is the given name of an AI object later in the code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you do not

instead use arguments

```
class Player():
    def __init__(self, canvas...):
        self.id = canvas.create_rectangle(...)
        ...
    def touching(self,other):
        aipos = canvas.coords(other.object)
        pos = canvas.coords(self.id)
        ...

    #the function above checks if the player is touching the AI if it 
    #is, then call other functions

class AI():
   def __init__(self, canvas...):
       self.id = canvas.create_rectangle(...)
   def chase(self,player):
       playerpos = canvas.coords(player.id)
       pos = canvas.coords(self.id)
```

then

```
player = Player(canvas...)
ai  = AI(...)
ai.chase(player)
player.touching(ai)
```

but even better is to define a base object type that defines your interface

```
class BaseGameOb:
     position = [0,0]
     def distance(self,other):
         return distance(self.position,other.position)

class BaseGameMob(BaseGameOb):
     def chase(self,something):
         self.target = something
     def touching(self,other):
         return True or False
```

then all your things inherit from this

```
class Player(BaseGameMob):
      ... things specific to Player

class AI(BaseGameMob):
      ... things specific to AI

class Rat(AI):
    ... things specific to a Rat type AI
```

Comment: Making arguments for main functions work good for me - thanks

Answer (score 1):

You do not have a dependency cycle problem. But, you have the following problem,

1. You are trying it use an AI object, but you did not create the object anywhere. It needs to look like,

   `foo = AI() #creating the object
   bar(foo) #using the object`
2. The syntax is wrong around `canvas.coords(AI object)`.

   The way to call a function is `foo(obj)` without the type.

   When defining a function you can optionally mention the type like `def foo(bar : 'AI'):`

The proof you can depend classes on each other, https://pyfiddle.io/fiddle/b75f2de0-2956-472d-abcf-75a627e77204/

Answer (score 0):

You can initialize one without specifying the type and assign it in afterwards. Python kind of pretends everyone are grown-ups so..

e.g.:

```
class A:
    def __init__(self, val):
        self.val = val
        self.b = None

class B:
    def __init__(self, a_val):
        self.a = A(a_val)

a_val = 1
b = B(1)
a = b.a
a.b = b
```